# RecyclerView on Fragment white page

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview

I have create a fragment for tab and i put a RecyclerView in this fragement follow the code:

Fragment 1 Java:

```
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        mView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_two, container, false);
        mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) mView.findViewById(R.id.my_recycler_view);
        mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getContext());
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
        mAdapter = new MyRecyclerViewAdapter(getDataSet());
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_two, container, false);
    }
```

Fragment 1 XML:

```
    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/my_recycler_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:scrollbars="vertical"/>
```

Activity call fragment tab:

```
 private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
            ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
            adapter.addFragment(new OneFragment(), "Cliente");
            adapter.addFragment(new TwoFragment(), "Prodotti");
            viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
        }

        class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
            private final List<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
            private final List<String> mFragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();

            public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager manager) {
                super(manager);
            }

            @Override
            public Fragment getItem(int position) {
                return mFragmentList.get(position);
            }

            @Override
            public int getCount() {
                return mFragmentList.size();
            }

            public void addFragment(Fragment fragment, String title) {
                mFragmentList.add(fragment);
                mFragmentTitleList.add(title);
            }

            @Override
            public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
                return mFragmentTitleList.get(position);
            }
        }
```

I don't have any error but Debug says:

```
E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout
```

I have searched on google but nothing solve my problem, do you have any suggestion?? If you need more code just ask, thanks in any case..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem lies in the lines

```
    mView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_two, container, false);
    ........

    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_two, container, false);
```

When you wrote `return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_two, container, false);` you are re-inflating view and returning new view which does not have anything initialised.

---

You just need to return view which you inflated before (i.e. `mView`).

So you code must be like

```
mView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_two, container, false);
        mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) mView.findViewById(R.id.my_recycler_view);
        mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getContext());
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
        mAdapter = new MyRecyclerViewAdapter(getDataSet());
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

        return mView;
```

Comment: Thanks so much =)